# Another way to implement < in C

Tags: c, count, bit-manipulation, computer-science, bitwise-operators

I'm having trouble writing the correct code to return `1 + x` if `x < 5`, return `1` otherwise.

Problem specifications:

- Return `1 + x` if `x < 5`, return `1` otherwise (this ensures that `1 <= f(x) <= 5`)
- Example `counter1To5(2) = 3`
- Example `counter1To5(5) = 1`
- Allowed operators for use: `~` `&` `!` `|` `+` `<<` `>>`
- Maximum number of operators: 15

This is what I have so far:

```
int counter1To5(int x) {
    return ((x + ~4) >> 31) & (x + 1);
}
```

Comment: Although not OP's key issue, `31` only makes sense if `int` is 32-bit.  Yet `int` may be other widths.

Comment: There is no "bitwise" `<` operator. That's just plain comparison.

Comment: "it will return x + 1 if x < 5 I think?" isn't really a question, but the best way to know if code does what you think is to test it. https://godbolt.org/z/ETEhfTqo1

Comment: `some_int >> 31` on a system with 32 bit `int` has no well-defined result in case `some_int` is negative. Stop using signed integers and bitwise operators together.

Comment: What I fail to see in your post (apart from an actual question...) is a definition of what your function is actually supposed to do. Two examples and some ranges are not sufficient definition. Please try for [ask]. Maybe, just in case it is applicable: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Well there is that ?-free thing in the title. But if that is the question then the answer is "By putting it between two operands in an expression."

Comment: The function needs to return 1 + x if x < 5, return 1 otherwise, in order to ensure that 1<= x <=5

Comment: `int foo1(int x) { if(x < 5) return 1 + x; return 1; }` or `int foo2(int x) { return x < 5 ? 1 + x : 1; }` or `int foo3(int x) { return 1 + x * (x < 5); }` - [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/5qYbWaz9r)

Comment: What about negative values of `x`?

Comment: I am guessing this is somekind of homework question. Please note that you will never use bitwise operators for this purpose in real life (excluding perhaps some very specific ultra rare optimization case), because it just results in unstable, hard to read, buggy, and brittle code.  Just use `if` statement.

Comment: Right-shifting a signed integer is extremely non-portable.  Whether a right shift is sign-preserving or not is implementation defined.

Comment: The best I can come up with so far doesn't do any bit-shifting but assumes 2's complement `int` representation (probably a safe assumption since C23 will require it): `return (x & (~(!!(x & INT_MIN) | !((x + 3) & ~7)) + 1)) + 1;`.

Comment: @jess To ensure 1 <= count1to5(x) <= 5, does that mean x cannot be negative?

Comment: @Andrew Henle is referring to "The result of E1 >> E2 is E1 right-shifted E2 bit positions. [...] If E1 has a signed type and a negative value, the resulting value is implementation-defined." But since you're already assuming a specific platform (by assuming `int` is a 32-bit two's complement), I don't see a problem assuming a certain behaviour from right-shift.

Comment: @Lundin was referring to that too, I believe.

Comment: Re "*The function needs to return 1 + x if x < 5, return 1 otherwise, in order to ensure that 1<= x <=5*", That doesn't ensure 1<= x <=5. Using that logic, counter1To5(-1) would produce 0, for example.

Comment: Is this an assignment? If not, what's the point?

Comment: My use of `INT_MIN` may be cheating a bit since its macro definition probably contains a unary `-` operator. My use of `INT_MIN` could be replaced with `~INT_MAX` (I'm already assuming 2's complement), giving: `return (x & (~(!!(x & ~INT_MAX) | !((x + 3) & ~7)) + 1)) + 1;`

Comment: My `x + 3` also has an arithmetic overflow that is UB when `x > INT_MAX - 3`.

Comment: This one assumes 2's complement but has no undefined behavior and uses 15 operators (assuming `INT_MAX` contains no hidden operators): `return (x & (!((x & ~INT_MAX) | !(x & ~4) | !(x & ~3)) + ~0)) + 1;`.

Comment: `int counter1To5(int x) { switch (x) { default: return 1; case 1: case 2: case 3: case 4: return x + 1;} }`

Comment: @pmg That'd give the wrong result for negative `x`s according to the problem specification.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I just went with "ensures that `1 <= f(x) <= 5`"

Comment: @pmg Ah... I missed that part.

Comment: Your solution is almost correct, you just need to move two parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to post a whole answer, but I guess what you are looking for is some kind of *operator* way to determine whether `x` is greater than `5`.

```
  !((x - 1) >> 2)

  ^    ^      ^
  |    |      |
  |    |    Here you shift the bits that are not necessary out of the integer
  |    |
  |  By subtracting here you make sure, that 5 is the smallest integer to not
  |  be shifted out
  |
 Negating the value to get 1 or 0 as an output
```

I did not test, but this should return a `0` if `x` is indeed greater than `4` and return `1` if `x` is smaller than `5`. Beware that i am in no shape or form an expert. I did not account for negative values and there probably are smarter ways to solve your problem. If it's a homework no doubt you professor will show you proudly.

Edit: Yes `>>` is risky business for portable code, but this is hardly something he wants to implement for real somewhere.

Comment: The `-` operator is not allowed.

Comment: Oh man you're right. I did not even notice `-` was not allowed. But since addition with negative values is allowed, this should be a minor problem.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `int` has a 2's complement representation (which should be a safe assumption since C23 will require signed integer types to have a 2's complement representation), this function definition satisfies the condition that it should return `x + 1` when `x < 5`, and return `1` when `x >= 5`, only use the `~`, `&`, `!`, `|`, `+`, `<<`, and `>>` operators, and use no more than 15 operators:

```
#include <limits.h>

int counter1To5(int x) {
    return (x & (!((x & ~INT_MAX) | !(x & ~4) | !(x & ~3)) + ~0)) + 1;
}
```

Breaking that `return` expression down:

1. `(x & ~INT_MAX)` will be `INT_MIN` when `x < 0`, or `0` when `x >= 0`. (Using `(x & INT_MIN)` would save an explicit operator, but the expansion of the `INT_MIN` macro would probably introduce an operator, and that operator would probably be the unary `-` operator, which is forbidden.)
2. `!(x & ~4)` will be `1` when `x == 0 || x == 4`, or `0` when `x != 0 && x != 4`.
3. `!(x & ~3)` will be `1` when `x >= 0 && x < 4`, or `0` when `x < 0 || x >= 4`.
4. OR-ing *2* and *3* above, `!(x & ~4) | !(x & ~3)` will be `1` when `x >= 0 && x < 5`, or `0` when `x < 0 || x >= 5`.
5. OR-ing *1* and *4* above, `(x & ~INT_MAX) | !(x & ~4) | !(x & ~3)` will be `INT_MIN` when `x < 0`, or `1` when `x >= 0 && x < 5`, or `0` when `x >= 5` (i.e. it will be non-zero if and only if `x < 5`).
6. Logically negating *5* above, `!((x & ~INT_MAX) | !(x & ~4) | !(x & ~3))` will be `1` when `x >= 5`, or `0` when `x < 5`.
7. Subtracting 1 from (by adding `~0` to) *6* above, `(!((x & ~INT_MAX) | !(x & ~4) | !(x & ~3)) + ~0)` will be `0` when `x >= 5`, or `-1` when `x < 5`.
8. Bitwise AND-ing `x` with *7* above, `(x & (!((x & ~INT_MAX) | !(x & ~4) | !(x & ~3)) + ~0))` will be `0` when `x >= 5`, or `x` when `x < 5`.
9. Finally adding 1 to *8* above, `(x & (!((x & ~INT_MAX) | !(x & ~4) | !(x & ~3)) + ~0)) + 1` will be `1` when `x >= 5`, or `x + 1` when `x < 5`, as required.

---

If `counter1To5(x)` should also return `1` when `x < 0`, the function definition can be simplified to:

```
int counter1To5(int x) {
    return (x & (!(!(x & ~4) | !(x & ~3)) + ~0)) + 1;
}
```